# Most elegant way to convert lists into igraph object for plotting

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to `igraph` and it seems to be a very powerful (and therefore also complex) package.

I tried to convert the following lists into an igraph object.

```
graph <- list(s = c("a", "b"),
              a = c("s", "b", "c", "d"),
              b = c("s", "a", "c", "d"),
              c = c("a", "b", "d", "e", "f"),
              d = c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f"),
              e = c("c", "d", "f", "z"),
              f = c("c", "d", "e", "z"),
              z = c("e", "f"))

weights <- list(s = c(3, 5),
                a = c(3, 1, 10, 11),
                b = c(5, 3, 2, 3),
                c = c(10, 2, 3, 7, 12),
                d = c(15, 7, 2, 11, 2),
                e = c(7, 11, 3, 2),
                f = c(12, 2, 3, 2),
                z = c(2, 2))
```

Interpretation is as follows: `s` is the starting node, it links to nodes `a` and `b`. The edges are weighted 3 for `s` to `a` and 5 for `s` to `b` and so on.

I tried all kinds of functions from `igraph` but only got all kinds of errors. What is the most elegant and easy way to convert the above into an `igraph` object for plotting the graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an edgelist and then a graph from that.  Assign the weights and plot it.

```
set.seed(123)

e <- as.matrix(stack(graph))
g <- graph_from_edgelist(e)
E(g)$weight <- stack(weights)[[1]]

plot(g, edge.label = E(g)$weight)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Using `stack` here is indeed very elegant - Thank you